# Convertir array que viene de mysql a una simple lista

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estoy tratando de dar formato de salida a un array a una simple lista de fechas pero no lo consigo.

Estoy usando esto:

```
$CFestivos = Consulta("Array","`Fecha_Ini`","Prerrogativas","`Id_Usuario` = 0");
$festivos = array_values($CFestivos);
        
print_r($festivos);
```

La salida que me da es:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Fecha_Ini] => 2023-01-16 ) [1] => Array ( [Fecha_Ini] => 2023-01-16 ) [2] => Array ( [Fecha_Ini] => 2024-01-06 ) [3] => Array ( [Fecha_Ini] => 2023-05-01 ) [4] => Array ( [Fecha_Ini] => 2023-04-07 ) [5] => Array ( [Fecha_Ini] => 2023-01-02 ) [6] => Array ( [Fecha_Ini] => 2023-01-06 ) )
```

Y la salida que necesito es:

```
$festivoss= array("2008-12-25","2008-12-26","2013-01-01");
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que me quite todas las keys del array para que solo ponga las fechas tal cual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener una lista de fechas sin las claves asociadas al array multidimensional que estás usando actualmente, puedes utilizar la función `array_column()` en combinación con un bucle `foreach` para extraer los valores de la columna `Fecha_Ini`.

Un ejemplo:

```
$CFestivos = Consulta("Array","`Fecha_Ini`","Prerrogativas","`Id_Usuario` = 0");
$festivos = array_values($CFestivos);

// Utilizamos array_column() para obtener los valores de la columna Fecha_Ini
$fechas = array_column($festivos, 'Fecha_Ini');

// Creamos una nueva lista de fechas sin las claves asociadas al array
$festivoss = array();
foreach ($fechas as $fecha) {
    $festivoss[] = $fecha;
}

// Imprimimos la lista de fechas
print_r($festivoss);
```

Esto generará una salida del tipo:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 2023-01-16 
    [1] => 2023-01-16 
    [2] => 2024-01-06 
    [3] => 2023-05-01 
    [4] => 2023-04-07 
    [5] => 2023-01-02 
    [6] => 2023-01-06 
)
```

Comment: el array_values de arriba también sobraría ¿verdad?

Comment: No se puede quitar el [0], ya que el primer subíndice. Si lo que quieres es eliminar el primer elemento puedes hacer uso de la función `array_shift()`, que elimina el primer elemento del array y reorganiza los índices restantes, pero siempre vas a tener un [0], que es tu primer elemento.
Si te sirvió la respuesta, márcala como correcta para que le sirva a futuras personas.

Comment: Disculpa que has respondido antes que editase mi respuesta, lo he probado y funciona con el [0]

Comment: @Londo, para obtener el resultado con `array_column($festivos, 'Fecha_Ini')` alcanza. El resto es innecesario.